# In a variadic function template can the return type be deduced from the template parameter pack elements

Tags: c++, variadic-functions, auto

I am trying to write a variadic function template.
The first argument to the function is an integer index value.
The rest of the (variable number of) arguments represent the variable number of arguments.
This function must return the argument at the location index.
For example, if function is invoked as

```
`find_item(1, -1, "hello", 'Z', 10.03)`
```

it must return `"hello"`

If invoked as

```
find_item(2, -1, "hello", 'Z', 10.03)
```

it must return `'Z'`

If invoked as

```
find_item(3, -1, "hello", 'Z', 10.03, 'Q', 100)
```

it must return `10.03` etc....

I was trying something like the following code :

```
template <class T>
auto find_item(int inx, T val) { return val ;}

// GENERAL CASE
template <class T, class... Others>
auto find_item(int inx, T a1, Others ... others) {
    if(inx==0) return a1 ;
    else return print(inx-1, others...) ;
}

int main() {
    cout<<find_item(1, -1, "hello", string("abvd"), 10.03)<<endl ; ;
}
```

This code does not compile because the return type not being uniform, can not be deduced.
I want to know if there is any way that this can be achieved. Or is it an invalid use case all together.
If this can be achieved, then how.

Comment: Is the index known at compile time? You can make it template parameter in this case

Comment: return type cannot depend of runtime value.

Comment: No I don't want to fix the index

Comment: There are std::variant and std::any that somewhat allow returning different types. What do you REALLY want to achieve?

Comment: C++ is a strongly typed language.  What you are explicitly asking for is not possible.  If the compiler doesn't know what type is returned from a function call, the compiler also doesn't know what can be done with the return value.

Comment: Another question is what are you going to do with the returned value. You need a polymorphic interface that uniformly accepts all this values, like numerous overloads of operator<<(ostream&, T)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know if there is any way that this can be achieved.

No.

In C/C++ (that are statically typed languages) the type returned from a function **must** depends from the **types** of the arguments, not from the values.

So the types returned from the following calls

```
find_item(1, -1, "hello", 'Z', 10.03);
find_item(2, -1, "hello", 'Z', 10.03);
find_item(3, -1, "hello", 'Z', 10.03);
```

**must** be the same.

Point.

You can get around this rule returning a `std::variant` (that can contain values of different types), or a `std::any` (that can contain generic values), but a type that is determined independently from the received value.

Different if you pass the index of type/value you want (the first argument, in your case) as a template parameter.

I mean: different if you call `find_item()` as follows

```
find_item<1>(-1, "hello", 'Z', 10.03);
find_item<2>(-1, "hello", 'Z', 10.03);
find_item<3>(-1, "hello", 'Z', 10.03);
```

Now `find_item<1>()` can return a `char const *`, `find_item<2>()` can return a `char` and `find_item<3>()` can return a `double`.

This is because `find_item<1>()`, `find_item<2>()` and `find_item<3>()` are different functions, so can have different return types.

But... this way... we've almost obtained the [`std::get<>()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get) that extract values from a `std::tuple`.

Unfortunately you can use this solution only when the index (the template parameter) is known compile time.

In other words, you can't make something as follows

```
for ( auto i = 1 ; i < 4 ; ++i )
 { // .............NO! ---V
   auto value = find_item<i>(-1, "hello", 'Z', 10.03);
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Since your return type is determined by the run time variable `inx`, there is no way to know the exact return type of `find_item` at compile time.

What you need to do is type erasure. You can return `std::variant<Args...>` and construct it with the corresponding arguments based on the value of `inx`. For example:

```
#include <variant>
#include <array>
#include <tuple>

template<class... Args>
constexpr auto find_item(std::size_t index, Args... args) {
  constexpr auto indices = []<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    using var_t = std::variant<std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Is>...>;
    return std::array{var_t{std::in_place_index<Is>}...};
  }(std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{});

  return std::visit([&...args = args](auto i) {
    return std::variant<Args...>{
      std::in_place_index<i>,
      std::get<i>(std::tuple(args...))};
  }, indices[index]);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6WsW4MeYc)

Another way of type erasure is to use function pointers:

```
#include <variant>
#include <array>
#include <tuple>

template<class... Args>
constexpr auto find_item(std::size_t index, Args... args) {
  constexpr auto funcs = []<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return std::array{ +[](Args... args) { 
      return std::variant<Args...>(
        std::in_place_index<Is>, std::get<Is>(std::tuple(args...))); 
      }... };
  }(std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{});

  return funcs[index](args...);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/WhGhE3MT5)

Comment: Great solution, I learned a lot! What is a benefit of making ```indices``` ```constexpr```?

Comment: @erzya `indices` is obviously a compile-time constant variable, so there's no reason not to make it `constexpr`.

Answer (score 2):

This is not C++ idiomatic way to deal with it, but you can model returning different types with std::variant. `variant_cast` is a helper that converts `variant<T...>` to `variant<S...>` where S is a superset of T.

```
#include <variant>
#include <iostream>

template <class... Args>
struct variant_cast_proxy
{
    std::variant<Args...> v;

    template <class... ToArgs>
    operator std::variant<ToArgs...>() const
    {
        return std::visit([](auto&& arg) -> std::variant<ToArgs...> { return arg ; },
                          v);
    }
};

template <class... Args>
auto variant_cast(const std::variant<Args...>& v) -> variant_cast_proxy<Args...>
{
    return {v};
}


template <class T>
std::variant<T> find_item(int inx, T val) { return val ;}

// GENERAL CASE
template <class T, class... Others>
std::variant<T, Others...> find_item(int inx, T a1, Others ... others) {
    if(inx==0) return a1 ;
    else return variant_cast(find_item<Others...>(inx-1, others...)) ;
}



int main() {
    std::visit([](auto v){std::cout << v << std::endl;}, 
               find_item(1, -1, "hello", std::string("abvd"), 10.03)) ;
}
```